# ECMA6 class-based controller with babel and ng-annotate/ngInject results in ReferenceError

Tags: angularjs, ecmascript-6, webpack, babeljs, ng-annotate

I've an Angular 1.4 controller with a method that depends on a resource service. I've annotated the constructor of that class with `ng-annotate`, but still, Angular curses that service can't be found in the method:

```
var MyResourceFactory = require("myResource.service");

class MyController {
    // @ngInject
    constructor($location, $stateParams, $state, MyResource) {
        ... // some initialization code
    }

    myMethod(data) {
        var resource = new MyResource();
        resource.data = data;
        resource.save();
    }
}

module.exports = angular.module("MyModule", [])
    .factory('MyResource', MyResourceFactory)
    .controller('MyController', MyController)
    .config(routes);
```

But, on the very first line of `myMethod` (`var resource = new MyResource()`) execution fails:

```
ReferenceError: MyResource is undefined
    at MyController.myMethod (myModule.module.js:214)
    ...
```

Technologies used:

- Angular 1.4
- Webpack
- Babel
- ng-annotate

How to apply ngInject to an ECMA6-class method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MyResource` is a variable local to constructor method and it's not available outside. Usual approach in such cases, is to make it public property:

```
class MyController {
    // @ngInject
    constructor($location, $stateParams, $state, MyResource) {
        this.MyResource = MyResource;
        // ... some initialization code
    }

    myMethod(data) {
        var resource = new this.MyResource();
        resource.data = data;
        resource.save();
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, ever so simple. Time I went to sleep. Thank you!

Comment: Is there a way to do this without exposing the Angular service on my controller? I just don't want to expose the service calls directly to the view.